# angular with firebase event handling

Tags: angularjs, events, event-handling, firebase

Im making a poll app where people can create a new poll (question and responses) then that gets pushed to my firebase database and the questions get populated as a list in the left  side bar. I got that far and it works great.

Now i'm trying to make the take a poll feature so when a person clicks on the question they want to respond to, it updates the view for just that one question and ng-repeat for the number of responses there are.

Is there a firebase event handling similar to jquerys on click for .this to do this? How can I accomplish this, I feel stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. For the nav bar on the left in my anchor tag within a ng repeat. I used a ng-click = "select(poll)" where poll being the ng-repeat = poll in polls

then in my controller I have this simple function

```
$scope.select = function(poll){
  $scope.selected = poll;
};
```

which then in my takeApollview (i'm using ui-router) I just use the selected to display all the key values.

Msg me if anyone has a similar problem and needs guidance.